# How to add charts to mail body in PHP

Tags: php, charts

I need to add a chart to my auto generated mail in PHP, after following the documentation from https://quickchart.io/documentation/ I have initiated a method as follows,

```
$chartConfig_datavolume = "{
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: [$date_array2_new],
      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(2, 39, 107)',
          borderColor: 'rgb(2, 39, 107)',
          data: [$value_array2_datavolume],
          fill: false,
        }
      ],
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Total Volume',
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
       scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
         max: 5000 ,
         min: 3000

        }
      }]
     },


    },
  }";



  $chartUrl_datavolume = 'https://quickchart.io/chart?w=400&h=200&c=' . urlencode($chartConfig_datavolume);

  $messagenew.=nl2br(" \r\n \r\n");
  $messagenew.= "Please see chart below:<br><br><img src=\"$chartUrl_datavolume\">";
```

This code will generate a chart as I need but the issue is with the scale,

```
scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
             max: 5000 ,
             min: 3000
    
            }
          }]
         },
```

When I remove this part, the chart is generating but when I add this part chart is not generating.  But with the editor used in quickchart, I could generate a chart with this part as well. Can someone help me to solve this issue.

Note: I am using this script in my RHEL 8 server and PHP 7.2.24 is installed on it

Comment: Did you try to add a width to the `img` tag? `<img src=\"$chartUrl_datavolume\" width=\"100%\">`

Comment: width and height is already added,at the encoding process. Need to add there as well?

Comment: Yes, try it with `100%` so it scales to the container containing the graph. I think that will fix it.